# Cannot Inherit from final Snackbar

Tags: android

Recently, I created a class with my own version of a Toast. All working fine.

Now, I am trying to create a class with a version of a Snackbar and I have:

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

public class Snack extends Snackbar{

}
```

Android Studio won't let me extend Snackbar, it displays the message:

```
"Cannot inherit from final 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar'
```

Why does this happen? I did Google it a lot, but could not find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Snackbar` is a `final` class and you can't create a subclass of a `final` class.
for example, `String` class in Java is also final and you can't derive any class from `String` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend a `final` class, that is the intention of the `final` keyword in java

you can use this library if you want a customized SnackBar

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2659